# JQuery id testing fails, animation system with seperate divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a new sort of menu with 4 squares in the middle of the screen, and when you hover over the squares they enlarge, each in a different direction so they don't overlap. I already got the animation part and basic part right, only thing is, how do I get them to move in different directions? I already solved this by adding an if statement that gets the id of the element and using that to find out where the square is located. However, this statement failed, I think at the part where it checks the id. I could use some help figuring it out, because I basically tried everything to make it work. Thanks in advance!

Here's the JSFiddle with the working animations: https://jsfiddle.net/2qkv1xua/
Here's the same JSFiddle, but with an added if-statement: https://jsfiddle.net/2qkv1xua/1/

And of course the code:

[HTML]

```
<body>
    <div id="menu_holder">
        <div class="menuItem" id="menu_item_1"></div>
        <div class="menuItem" id="menu_item_2"></div>
        <div class="menuItem" id="menu_item_3"></div>
        <div class="menuItem" id="menu_item_4"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[CSS]

```
* {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
#menu_holder {
    position: absolute;
    width: 410px;
    height: 410px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 105px;
    top: calc(50% - 305px);
    left: calc(50% - 305px);
}
.menuItem {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
}
#menu_item_1 {
    margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
    background-color: rgb(190, 184, 235);
}
#menu_item_2 {
    margin: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    background-color: rgb(139, 157, 195);
}
#menu_item_3 {
    margin: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    background-color: rgb(82, 153, 211);
}
#menu_item_4 {
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    background-color: rgb(11, 85, 99);
}
```

[JS]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menuItem').hover(
        if (this.attr('id') == "#menu_item_1") {
            function () {
                $(this).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
                    width: "300px",
                    height: "300px",
                    marginTop: "-100px",
                    marginLeft: "-100px"
                });
            },
            function () {
                $(this).animate({
                    width: "200px",
                    height: "200px",
                    marginTop: "0",
                    marginLeft: "0"
                });
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: You could also specify a hover handler for each item ... $('#menu_item_1').hover( ... ); etc,  adding a custom animation for each item.  However, you will run into issues of the items rearranging themselves within the menu_holder if you expand the width and marginRight of  menu_item_2.

Comment: @JohnSheridan Played around a little bit, turned out I had no rearranging issues (?). It's not the nicest way to do it but it definitely works with as less possible HTML. So thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

With wrappers around each menu_item and everything absolutely positioned, you can do it like this :

```html
<div id="menu_holder">
    <div class="menuWrapper" id="menu_wrapper_1"><div class="menuItem" id="menu_item_1"></div></div>
    <div class="menuWrapper" id="menu_wrapper_2"><div class="menuItem" id="menu_item_2"></div></div>
    <div class="menuWrapper" id="menu_wrapper_3"><div class="menuItem" id="menu_item_3"></div></div>
    <div class="menuWrapper" id="menu_wrapper_4"><div class="menuItem" id="menu_item_4"></div></div>
</div>
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
#menu_holder {
    position: absolute;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    border: 1px dashed #999;
}
.menuWrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 87px;
    height: 87px;
}
#menu_wrapper_1 {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#menu_wrapper_2 {
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#menu_wrapper_3 {
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#menu_wrapper_4 {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.menuItem {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
#menu_item_1 {
    background-color: rgb(190, 184, 235);
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#menu_item_2 {
    background-color: rgb(139, 157, 195);
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#menu_item_3 {
    background-color: rgb(82, 153, 211);
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#menu_item_4 {
    background-color: rgb(11, 85, 99);
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

```javascript
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menuItem').hover(function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            width: "80px",
            height: "80px"
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            width: "50px",
            height: "50px"
        });
    });
});
```

*I reduced the sizes to make the demo better in the small fiddle frame*

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2qkv1xua/4/)**

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much for your effort. I see that it is in fact working, however I do not like the way it uses wrappers to accomplish it. Is there really no way of doing this by using margins? >> Don't get me wrong here, I really appreciate your effort and I will not hesitate to utilize your code. Also I changed the `.stop()` in the first one with `.filter(':not(:animated)')`, this way it completes the whole animation. I just like it better.

Comment: Yes, but the CSS gets more complicated. You lose the simplicity of top:0, left:0, bottom:0, right:0. Maybe it wouldn't be too bad but personally I would live with the wrappers - the overhead is tiny.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. its working.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.menuItem').hover(function(){

            if ($(this).attr('id') == "menu_item_1") {
                    $(this).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
                        width: "300px",
                        height: "300px",
                        marginTop: "-100px",
                        marginLeft: "-100px"
                    });


                    $(this).animate({
                        width: "200px",
                        height: "200px",
                        marginTop: "0",
                        marginLeft: "0"
                    });
            }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Yes, it kind of works but immediately after I hover over the square, it will revert back to its original state. This is probably caused by the fact that it's not all in one function.
Also, when hovering out of the box, it will execute the animation again.